# forech shows one row less than the database

Tags: php, html, pdo

i have an if statement that if something exist in my table with a certain condition, it displays html dynamically with data from the database for each row that exists, i'm using a foreach loop, but it keeps showing on row less than what's in the actual table, if it there was three rows, it'll display two, if there was only one it displays nothing, it goes through the if statement because if it doesn't it displays an error message, but in my case it just displays a blank page, why is this happening?

```
function show()
{
   
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT offered_rides.*, reg.*
                                FROM offered_rides
                                 JOIN reg ON offered_rides.phone = reg.phone where 
                                 offered_rides.date = :date AND offered_rides.seats >= :seats AND offered_rides.start = :start AND offered_rides.finish = :finish ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':date',$this->date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':seats',$this->seats);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start',$this->from);
    $stmt->bindParam(':finish',$this->to);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    
    
   if($row)   
   { 
           
      foreach($stmt as $row):
            
          
         ?>

        <form action="Update.php" method="POST">
            
            <div class="a">
                
                <div class="fnamelname">
                <p style="display:inline;"> <?php echo $row["fname"];?>  </p>
                <p style="display:inline;"> <?php echo $row["lname"];?> </p>
                </div>
                    
            </div>
                
            
            //i need to store these to use them later
            <input type = "hidden" name = "phone-D" value = "<?=$row['phone'] ?>" />
            <input type = "hidden" name = "time" value = "<?= $row['time'] ?>" />
            <input type = "hidden" name = "seats" value = "<?= $row['seats'] - $this->seats?>" />
             
            
        </form>

        <?php endforeach; 
        
        
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes absolutely no sense: `foreach($stmt as $row):`. `$stmt` is not an array, it is a single object. Instead you should use a `while` loop with the `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` step as condition. Because the `fetch()` method returns a single row each time it is called. That is what you want.

```
function show() {
   
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT offered_rides.*, reg.* FROM offered_rides JOIN reg ON offered_rides.phone = reg.phone WHERE  offered_rides.date = :date AND offered_rides.seats >= :seats AND offered_rides.start = :start AND offered_rides.finish = :finish ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':date',$this->date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':seats',$this->seats);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start',$this->from);
    $stmt->bindParam(':finish',$this->to);
    $stmt->execute();


    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>

        <form action="Update.php" method="POST">                
            <div class="a">
                <div class="fnamelname">
                <p style="display:inline;"> <?php echo $row["fname"];?>  </p>
                <p style="display:inline;"> <?php echo $row["lname"];?> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            //i need to store these to use them later
            <input type = "hidden" name = "phone-D" value = "<?=$row['phone'] ?>" />
            <input type = "hidden" name = "time" value = "<?= $row['time'] ?>" />
            <input type = "hidden" name = "seats" value = "<?= $row['seats'] - $this->seats?>" />
        </form>

        <?
    }
}
```

And a hint: when using "short tags" in php in a consequent manner your html markup get's much easier to read:

```
        <form action="Update.php" method="POST">                
            <div class="a">
                <div class="fnamelname">
                <p style="display:inline;"><?= $row["fname"]?></p>
                <p style="display:inline;"><?= $row["lname"]?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            //i need to store these to use them later
            <input type="hidden" name="phone-D" value="<?=$row['phone']?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?= $row['time']?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="seats" value="<?= $row['seats'] - $this->seats?>"/>
        </form>
```